# How to avoid daily uploading of files to PCF

Tags: pcf

I have my Dash plotly app running in PCF, my app.py runs based on a excel file which is uploaded to pcf along with app.py, but the excel feed changes daily, so daily i am uploading the new file to pcf using "cf push", is it possible to avoid that, like making pcf to read excel from my file system instead of uploading the new excel file to pcf cell container everytime

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need some persistent storage attached to your container so app can refer the available file at run time. There are the options that can be explored:

- If NFS is enabled at your end then you can mount the file share and pick the files from that location directly.
- Otherwise you can have another PCF service
  (just to keep it separate for better management) that can pull the
  files from your server using sftp and transfer to S3. Amend your app
  to refer the file from S3.

Comment: thanks for that, yeah i have my files in NAS shared drive, i explored smb volume services in pcf, but when i try to mount them its throwing error

 App instance exited with guid 3d3cedd6-5254-4401-8a6d-ad982673fd30 payload: {"instance"=>"121f47d7-692f-4664-6f62-844c", "index"=>0, "cell_id"=>"93c96a05-748b-457d-bd15-1aa4680729fe", "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_description"=>"failed to mount volume, errors: exit status 32", "crash_count"=>7, "crash_timestamp"=>1609147445720443954, "version"=>"7e8a878e-d697-4091-982f-28ab0c977899"}

Comment: It seems The NFS server is rejecting the connection for the some reason. Server Messaging protocol (SMB) is the native file sharing protocol implemented in Windows systems. The Network File System (NFS) protocol is used by Linux systems to share files and folders. Do you have windows file server and PCF got windows stack available? Otherwise SMB might not be ideal. Can you enable the debug logs and see if it gives some more information?